# What if Eva knows the value of S or C in RSA?

Tags: rsa

we all know the RSA-authentication but I have some question about the security of the system if Eve knows the value of:

1) S

2) C

3) d

I think that RSA is not less secure if she know S, but it is less secure if she knows C or d. Am I right? Why?

[image]

Comment: Alice must receive $P$ from (and randomly generated by) Bob-White-Rabbit; otherwise, to what would $P$ on the bottom right be compared? $n_A\le n_B$ must hold, otherwise occasionally $S\ge n_B$ and Bob's decryption fails. $n_A\ne n_B$ should hold for different reasons. In 3), it is not clear if Eve-Queen-of-Hearts gets $d_A$ or $d_B$. Independently: I guess this is homework, so I'll give hints. You are Eve-Queen-of-Hearts, and are in situation 1, 2, or 3: can you send what the rightful Alice would have sent (which obviously would pass the test Bob does with $P$ on the bottom right)?

Comment: @fgrieu is it dangerous when Eve knows the value for S?

Comment: It would be dangerous if that allowed Eve to compute the rightful $C$. Can she?

Comment: @fgrieu No, i think she can't compute C by knowing S! But why is it dangerous if she knows the value of C?

Comment: What does Eve know besides $S$ that would help her find $C$? Also: again, one obvious way for Eve to succeed (as far as we can tell, pass some verification aimed at Bob checking if is there) is to send what the rightful Alice would have sent. What is that? Independently: as pointed in my first comment, the current question (and perhaps you) is missing how $P$ starts live in the first place, and the nature of the verification (that was on the bottom right of the whiteboard picture in the original [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/54841/1), but is now missing.

Comment: @fgrieu Eve only knows the public key of Alice and bob! So (e,n). P is just the plain text where you start from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71927/discussion-between-fgrieu-and-lene-coenen).